# Dom Manipulation - altering the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, dom, nodes

Would anyone know why I’m able to get my code to run on codepen, but not on my desktop? I keep getting a “can't read appendChild” error when I run my code on my desktop. I am new to coding and just started teaching my self how to manipulate the DOM.

https://codepen.io/unicorn1/pen/JpYqjJ

```
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
const content = document.createElement('div');
content.classList.add('content');
content.textContent = 'Dom text-content!';
container.appendChild(content);
```

Error Message

[image]

Comment: Where have you positioned your JS in desktop code? It matters. Ideally have your JS at the bottom just before the body ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the script should be put at the bottom before the body ends

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>
    THE TITLE OF YOUR WEBPAGE
  </h1>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
    const container = document.querySelector('#container');

    const content = document.createElement('div');
    content.classList.add('content');
    content.textContent = 'Dom text-content!';

    container.appendChild(content);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

or you can put the content of script in the window.onload callback like this:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
        const container = document.querySelector('#container');

        const content = document.createElement('div');
        content.classList.add('content');
        content.textContent = 'Dom text-content!';

        container.appendChild(content);

    };
    </script>
    <h1>
        THE TITLE OF YOUR WEBPAGE
      </h1>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

the principle is that,you can manipulate DOM after the DOM have loaded;you can't manipulate DOM before loaded.that is how window.onload and script position works;
also ,you can change the window.onload to DOMContentLoaded

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const container = document.querySelector('#container');

        const content = document.createElement('div');
        content.classList.add('content');
        content.textContent = 'Dom text-content!';

        container.appendChild(content);

    }, false);
    </script>
    <h1>
            THE TITLE OF YOUR WEBPAGE
          </h1>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```